# SQL command doesn't execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple code, and I've been using similar template in other files,but seems I just can't make this one work(
The problem is that the first $sqlCommand executes well, and after this any other doesn't work..Even after replacing the rest of the code(after first $sqlCommand) with some simple sql statement the table is not updated(it is the same with any other table).All priileges are granted. I just can't figure out what's wrong here...Thanks in advance for help

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","moviegallary")
       or die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());
$sqlCommand = "update movie set title='$_GET[title2]', category='$_GET[category2]',   movieDesc='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['moviedesc2'])."',image='".mysql_real_escape_st ring($_GET['poster2'])."' where movieCode=$_GET[moviecode2];";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand))
{
    die ('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
echo '<h1>1 record in "movie" table updated</h1>';

foreach ($_GET['new_star'] as $new_star)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from artist where concat(firstName,' ', lastName)='$new_star'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count>0) {
        $sqlCommand="insert into role select  $_GET[moviecode2], artistID from artist where concat(firstName,' ', lastName)='$new_star ;";
        echo '<h1>1 record in "role" table is inserted</h1>';
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. It's even more perplexing since you DO call mysqli_real_escape_string in one spot...

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Presumably `mysql_real_escape_st ring` is just a pasting error, rather than how your code really is?

Answer (score 4):

You're not executing the `INSERT` statement.

```
mysqli_query($con, $sqlCommand);
```

You need to start using prepared statements as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed mysqli_query($con, $sqlCommand);
but with the last one it still doesn't work

Comment: Caught errors after every mysqli_query, turned out I'm just missing one quote..Sorry for spamming here)